# BTC Treasure Hunt Volume 2

Tags: wallet, exchanges, wallet-recovery, lost-bitcoins, mobile

Similar to Whoiszo, I too am helping a friend locate a bitcoin treasure.

In a period between 2010 and 2011 my friend owned a blackberry curve 8330. At the time she was into some online gambling and because many of the gambling sites were becoming illegal in the US, she thought she would try putting some money in Bitcoin, which seemed like it would be easier to use on the gambling sites. She remembers buying the bitcoin and even had an app on her blackberry that she could access the exchange to keep an eye on the value. She decided to never spend it and eventually got a new phone and forgot about the bitcoin, which is reasonable considering it wasnt worth much at the time.  Fast forward to 2017 when bitcoin began to move rapidly, she remembered the bitcoin she had and tried to locate it. Unfortunately the phone was gone, the email service she had at the time was no longer in business and the email account could no longer be accessed. To top it off she cannot remember the name of the exchange or the app she used to access the bitcoin.
When I was speaking the other day about investing cyrpto market she explained her situation to me and she asked for my help. Of course I was very intrigued but skeptical. I thought surely she is mistaken. However she mentioned a few numbers , How many she bought and the amount she owned and after checking  the numbers are consistent with what the price of BTC was at that time. Also the fact that she said she could access it and monitor the value for that time means she would have had to definitely have purchased it. So now I have decided to help

what we have done so far:

1. tracked down the email service provider and followed the trail through about 3 different acquisitions of the company to arrive at the one that is currently functional. We got them on the phone and they said they have access to the @ ###.com email accounts however, hers for some reason could not be located.
2. Gone through years of bank statements searching for the transaction, hoping for a clue of the location or exchange with which it was made. - Nothing found in the bank statements, working on collecting all credit card statements from this time period now. (hoping it was not purchased with a gift card)
3. found and accessed her ###@sprint.blackberry.com account over the phone but was told there was no information there except the email address she had on file (same one as item 1).
4. Contacted Blackberry to see  if blackberry ID was required at the time she set up her phone and if so,, would that profile log information such as which apps were downloaded on the phone.
   (waiting on reply)

What I would like to do now is start from the opposite end and try to make the connection  back to her . my Plan is to try to figure out which exchanges  it could possible be  and see if an account was made in her name at any of them , however I am having ttrouble determining which exchanges it could possible have been. Does anyone recall any early cryptoexchanges  from this time period which  would be worth looking into?  does anyone recall accessing bitcoin holding account through aa blackberry app in this time period? which exchanges were even in existence in 2010 & 2011?

Im running out of  ideas and leads to pursue, where would you go from here?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated and if wyour suggestions lead me  on the trail to finding the lost bitcoin I will  dmake sure that you are rewarded!!

Comment: It seems she kept the Bitcoins in the exchange, can she remember any backup that the app might give her? Like 12 words or something like that? Because if she has something like this, it would be possible to recover the Bitcoins in another wallet.

Answer (score 1):

If it was between 2010-2011, it must have been MtGox [dead], Britcoin [dead], Bitmarket [dead], Bitstamp [alive], Kraken [alive]. If she's lucky, she used Bitstamp or Kraken.

She stored the BTC on the exchange or did she ever transfer any to a wallet?

If you know the company or individual who owns the domain her email was registered on, I'm sure they'd be willing to register her username (probably would need to add some motivation by way of money).

I don't know of any exchange that would accept giftcards to fund your account, so there must be something in her bank statement or credit card statement to reveal where her funds went.

Also did she use her legal name to register on the exchange?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Any idea what happens to the open accounts on exchanges that go under?  Her bank statements came up empty but  Im hopeful to find something in her credit card statements from that time, which we are still collecting. Shes not too technically savvy so I doubt she did anything too creative with it . in the next comment  Ill paste an email I got from her yesterday that discusses the possible movement of the BTC.

Comment: "I was looking to play poker on the internet, so it would have been after that was banned, most likely because I always played on PokerStars until they quit letting USA players play. I found a poker site that would allow you to play with bitcoin, so I probably googled and followed a link to purchase the bitcoin.I don’t have any idea where I bought it. I thought it gave me a long email address or web address connected to bitcoin somehow.I don’t think I ever played with any of it because I tried once but couldn’t ever figure out how to get the bitcoin to go to the poker account....

Comment: ...I’m pretty sure the gambling site wasn’t one of the main ones like full tilt or party poker, etc., because I I would remember that. It seems like the exchange or wherever I put it  was considered a vault for the bitcoin at that time. So I may have bought it somewhere else and then put it there. I remember looking at it on my blackberry and being surprised that it was actually worth more than the amount I had bought"

Comment: well, if she never transferred the Bitcoin into the gambling site, then it's irrelevant which gambling site it was. Just need to have an idea of what exchange it was. and did she use her legal name to register on the exchange?

Comment: Yea she would have used her legal name. We will contact Kracken and Bistamp to see if her name and info were ever used to open an account. I will reply back on that update and on any findings with the credit card statements.